# How to have 2 move in effect when scroll javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello guys im trying to make 2 different move in effect when i scroll on my web (show from right and shown from left). How can i make it ? can somebody help me please, i already manage to make them show from the left side, how can i make the right part

Here's my code:
Reveal from left side

```
<div class="container-fluid padding salimheader">
  <div class="row padding">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center reveal">
      <h1>Salim Group</h1>
      <hr style="width:15%; border:3px solid; color:#caa461; margin:auto;">
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Reveal from right side

```
<div class="container-fluid padding">
  <div class="row padding">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center reveal">
      <h1>Sayung Group</h1>
      <hr style="width:15%; border:3px solid; color:#caa461; margin:auto;">
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.reveal{
    position: relative;
    transform: translateX(-150px);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.reveal.active {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Javascript code:

```
        window.addEventListener('scroll', reveal);

        function reveal(){
          var reveals = document.querySelectorAll('.reveal');

          for(var i=0; i< reveals.length; i++){
            var windowheight= window.innerHeight;
            var revealtop = reveals[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
            var revealpoint = 150;

            if(revealtop < windowheight - revealpoint){
              reveals[i].classList.add('active');
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a second reveal class which just has a positive 150px translate instead of negative:

```
.reveal-right {
    transform: translateX(150px);
}
```

You'll need to add both the `reveal` and the `reveal-right` class to any div you want this to work on.

Comment: hello thankyou for the respon, will it work for the javascript because the query selector is for reveal class
var reveals = document.querySelectorAll('.reveal'); ?

Comment: Yes it will. When using it just do `<div class="reveal reveal-right"></div>` (i.e. for the right ones, ensure you use BOTH classes)

Comment: oh yes it work perfectly, thankyou for the responses.